# Lookup_expr for dynamic field_names in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

**Model:**

```
class EmployeeModel(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**Serializer:**

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Viewset:**

```
class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = EmployeeModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
    filterset_class = EmployeeFilterSet
```

My **EmployeeFilterSet** looks as below:

```
class EmployeeFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
   
    first_name__equals = django_filters.CharFilter(method='get_first_name_equals', field_name='first_name')
    last_name__equals = django_filters.CharFilter(method='get_last_name_equals', field_name='last_name')

    def get_first_name_equals(self, queryset, field_name, value):
        query = Q()
        for q_query in [Q(first_name__iexact=name) for name in (value.split(',') if value else [])]:
            query |= q_query
        return queryset.filter(query).all()

     def get_last_name_equals(self, queryset, field_name, value):
        query = Q()
        for q_query in [Q(last_name__iexact=name) for name in (value.split(',') if value else [])]:
            query |= q_query
        return queryset.filter(query).all()
```

As we can see, both **get_first_name_equals** and **get_last_name_equals** have similar definitions. The only reason I have different methods is that the lookup expressions have different field name **first_name**__iexact and **last_name**__iexact in the for loop expression. Is there a way by which I can have a single method like get_equals() and form the lookup expression in the for loop expression based on the field_name passed? This would help avoid writing multiple functions doing similar lookup expression but with different field names.

Comment: Have you considered using `field_name` in a `dict` using expansion - e.g. `**{f"{field_name}__iexact": name}`?

Comment: @Rfroes87 thanks for the reply. I am not getting how exactly I need to do it. I tried this but doesn't work: ```for q_query in [Q{f"{field_name}__iexact": name} for name in (value.split(',') if value else [])]:```. Could you please help me with a function on how exactly this can be done? That would be very helpful.

Comment: Change it to `for q_query in [Q(**{f"{field_name}__iexact": name}) for name in (value.split(',') if value else [])]:` and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic function which (already) receives the `field_name` and creates a `dict` based on it concatenated with `__iexact`.

It would work like this:

```
class EmployeeFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
   
    first_name__equals = django_filters.CharFilter(method='get_field_equals', field_name='first_name')
    last_name__equals = django_filters.CharFilter(method='get_field_equals', field_name='last_name')

    def get_field_equals(self, queryset, field_name, value):
        query = Q()
        for q_query in [Q(**{f"{field_name}__iexact": name}) for name in (value.split(',') if value else [])]:
            query |= q_query
        return queryset.filter(query).all()
```

After expanding the dict with `**` the arguments to the `Q` object would look like the intended `Q(first_name__iexact=name)` and so on.